# how to render webapi data with standardized ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We have several developers developing projects that commonly invoke the same methods in WebAPI endpoints. However, WebAPI doesn't dictate the look and feel of the data. After the data is returned, each of us has to write rendering code for the data, sometimes with different layout.  This is a waste of time and inconsistent to say the least.  We are using both ASP.Net MVC and Angular SPA as our presentation layer.  Is there a way to pug in a strong typed standard ui (component or template) once and used by any project that invokes a certain WebAPI method so that it will use the plug-in to rend a standardized look and feel.  Say when the WebAPI method is GetPatientLabResult, then render in standardized lab ui template or partial page?  Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from returning canned HTML from WebAPI - but it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Maybe create a library of directives that binds the presentation to the web api call and share the library amongst your developers?

Comment: Isnt this exactly what a view is for?

Comment: @ Phil and paqogomez - but how to distribute the views or directives among projects and developers without copying/importing?
@Preston -  A restful Web API does not return HTML. That needs to be done in MVC controllers and returned as ViewResult. We try to avoid this step in each project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular.js, you should do it in directive. You can then use the directive in multiple places.

For example you write a directive call PatientLabResult and other developers can just do this `<PatientLabResult result="YourPatientLabResultVariable"></PatientLabResult>` in their respective page.